# ampersand fetch data from rest api

Tags: javascript, ampersand.js, ampersand-collection

I create collection with  ampersand-rest-collection like this :

```
module.exports= AmpersandRestCollection.extend({
    url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/58b42441110000011c1c43bf',
    mainIndex: '_id',
    indexes: ['otherId'],
    model:ProvincesModel
});
```

and use it like this :

```
let provinces = new ProvinceRestCollection();

        provinces.fetch();

        provinces.each(function(model){
        console.log("model : "+model);
    })
```

and response json data like this :

```
  [
    { _id: 1, otherId: 'a', name: 'Phil' },
    { _id: 2, otherId: 'b', name: 'Julie' },
    { _id: 3, otherId: 'c', name: 'Henrik' },
    { _id: 4, otherId: 'd', name: 'Jenn' }
]
```

App send GET request to rest service and receive json data in response 
successfuly ,but provinces collection is empty!!!

**How can I use response data after fetch() method ????**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ampersand.js (and every js library) fetches the data in an asynchronous way. That said, you can only access the items when the operation finished, the framework usually notifies you by a callback function. In ampersand you have to do something like this:

```
let provinces = new ProvinceRestCollection();

provinces.fetch({
    success: function() {
        provinces.each(function(model) {
            console.log("model : " + model);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for response, I try with above code but dont see any log in browser console

Comment: Did you check the network panel of the developer console? Is the data fetched?

Comment: yes I can see data received successfully  in network tab on dev console

Comment: I cant find a public bundle of this library, are you bundling your own with webpack for example?

Comment: yes I use webpack for bundeling and  import like this : let AmpersandRestCollection=require ("ampersand-rest-collection");